# Inline completion for SWT based application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I started developing a small plugin for eclipse that should provide inline completions.
When I render a single-line completion, it looks good:

[image]

I struggle with some issues when I try to render a multiline completion since I want to draw the next lines and push the preceding text to be after the completion text, but I can't figure out how to do that.

[image]

What I have done so far is listening to document changed event:

```
public class InlineDocumentListener implements IDocumentListener {
    private ITextViewer textViewer;
    private IPath path;
    private Optional<InlineCompletion> activeCompletion;

    public InlineDocumentListener(ITextViewer textViewer, IPath path) {
        this.textViewer = textViewer;
        this.path = path;
        this.activeCompletion = Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public void documentChanged(DocumentEvent event) {
        IDocument document = event.getDocument();
        int offset = event.getOffset() + event.getText().length();
        activeCompletion = Optional.of(new InlineCompletion(offset, fetchCompletion(), textViewer, document));
    }

    @Override
    public void documentAboutToBeChanged(DocumentEvent event) {
    }
}
```

and then draw the completion using the paint listener:

```
public class InlineCompletion implements org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener {
    private StyledText widget;
    private Completion completion;
    private int offset;

    public InlineCompletion(int offset, Completion completion, ITextViewer textViewer, IDocument document) {
        this.widget = textViewer.getTextWidget();
        this.completion = completion;
        this.offset = offset;

        widget.addPaintListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        String[] completionsLines = completion.text.split("\n", 2);
        Point p = widget.getLocationAtOffset(this.offset);
        e.gc.setForeground(new Color(128, 128, 128));
        e.gc.drawText(completionsLines[0], p.x, p.y, true);
        if (completionsLines.length > 1) {
            e.gc.drawText(completionsLines[1].replace("\t", "    "), 0, p.y + widget.getLineHeight(), true);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to use the StyleRange object with GlyphMetrics to increase the current line size, but it can't be applied to an empty text.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What paint listener is that? It is not a all clear where you are trying to do this.

Comment: @greg-449 Sorry, I edited the question and added more context.

Comment: I don't think there is going to be any way to make that work. If this is the Java editor it provides a lot of APIs for doing completions - you need to use those.